# divide one value by another

Tags: javascript, math

I have some code from someone but wondering why they might have used a function like this.

```
    this.viewable= 45;

    getGroups: function() {

        return Math.ceil( this.getList().length / this.viewable );
    }
```

Why would they divide the list length by a number viewable. 
The result is the amount of items that should be rendered on the screen. 
Why not just say 45 be the number. Is it meant to be a percentage of the list. Usually I will divide a large value by a smaller value to get the percentage.

Sorry if this seems like a stupid math question but my Math skills are crap :) And just trying to understand and learn some simple Math skills.

Comment: What did they say when you asked them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's returning the number of groups (pages) that are required to display the list.  The reason it's declared as a variable (vs. using the constant in the formula) is so that it can be modified easily in one place.  And likely this is part of a plugin for which the view length can be modified from outside, so this declaration provides a handle to it, with 45 being the default.

Comment: Ok I get that thanks, but i'm more looking to know why you would divide it by each other in the first place. Why not use a constant number instead of taking say (list().length) 700 / (constant value) 45. I guess I'm trying to understand why you would do this math.

Comment: Because it's likely that not every list is going to have the same number of items.  What makes you confident that 700 will be the length of the list in all scenarios?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but if you have a table with, say 25 items, and you want to paginate it across pages of 10 items each, you'll want to know that the table is 3 pages long so you can provide the visual cues on the front end for the user to jump directly to page 3.  But you wouldn't want them to be able to jump to page 4 in that scenario because it doesn't exist. So page count matters.  And that's why one might do that math. Plenty of JS grids do exactly this when paginating a full dataset.

Comment: Ok now I get you. I was using 700  as a example of number of items. That obviously can and will change. So in my case there would be 15 groups of items. 700/45 = 15.5555

Comment: @user1096509, no, in your case there will be 16 groups.  15 full groups plus one partial group.  And `Math.ceil()` rounds up to the next integer accordingly.

Comment: Right sorry that's what I meant. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

That will give the number of pages required to view them all.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you can fit 45 items on a page and this is calculating the number of pages.
Or something similar to that?

Answer (score 0):

This would return the **total number of pages**.

> Total items = 100 (for example)
>
> Viewable = 45
>
> 100 / 45 = 2.22222....
>
> Math.ceil(2.2222) = 3
>
> Therefore 3 pages

Answer (score 0):

judging by the function name "getGroups", viewable is the capacity to show items (probably some interface list size).
By doing that division we know how many pages the data is to be divided (grouped) in order to be viewed on the interface. The **ceil** functions guarantees that we don't left out partial pages, if we had come records left that don't fill a complete page, we still want to show them and therefor make them count for a page.